# Problem with toilet fill valve

Tags: bathroom, toilet

My toilet has started acting funny lately and I am not 100% the cause.

Basically after flushing water does not come back in through the fill valve. You can hear the water running but it is not going into the tank. I can get small amounts of water into the tank by pulling the float switch up and down about 20 or so times. When I pull it up and let it go back down a few small bubbles come up out of the connection to the fill valve.

It sort of sounds like I need a new fill valve but I am curious if there is something more that I should be looking at since there are bubbles coming out of the bottom of the valve.

I am not sure if this is relevant or not, but there is no water coming out of the tube going out of the valve into the overflow thing (the place where that tube connects to)

Sorry for the lack of technical wording!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just install a new fill valve. They are inexpensive and fairly easy to replace.

After disconnecting the old fill valve you can try turning on the water to see if you are getting water from the supply as expected. Use caution, as the water can shoot out all over the bathroom. If you are not getting water from the supply you likely have a different issue.